# jQuery disables css:hover class

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question is kind of a duplicate, but I have read through all the other answers, but none of them were helpful. I have an image where I want to zoom in on and be able to move with the mouse. Like the banner image on this website. https://www2.hotelspro.com/.

This is the code for my image

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" class="flickity-viewport">
```

I have a jQuery script that does the mouse movement and that works fine. Here is the code.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var lFollowX = 0,
lFollowY = 0,
x = 0,
y = 0,
friction = 1 / 10;

function moveBackground() {
x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1)';


$('.flickity-viewport').css({
'-webit-transform': translate,
'-moz-transform': translate,
'transform': translate
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - 
e.clientX));
var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - 
e.clientY));
lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;


});

moveBackground();

});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS that works fine on itself, but not with the jQuery

```
.flickity-viewport{
transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.flickity-viewport:hover{
transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I have tried !important and all the answers I have found here, but nothing works. Hope someone can help me :)

This is the Codepen that explains what I am talking about. I want to scale the image by a number and be able to move it around like that.
https://codepen.io/BilendM/pen/WBLmad

Answer (score 1):

Once your javascript has set `transform` on your element, the css is overridden. The reference site uses `transform:scale` to set the zoom on hover, and adjusts the `transform-origin` property based on the mouse movement.

Here's an example using much less js than your example. When the "zoom" feature is applied by `transform:scale`, it zooms in at the `transform-origin`. In this example, I am getting the current mouse position from the event passed in to the event handler, and setting the `transform-origin` to those coordinates. The "friction" is created using css transition timing. The zoom is still .2s but the movement is set to 1s so the image zooms quickly but repositions slowly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.flickity-viewport').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $(this).css('transform-origin', e.clientX + 'px ' + e.clientY + 'px');
  });

});
```

```css
.flickity-viewport {
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out,
    transform-origin 1s ease-out;
}

.flickity-viewport:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="flickity-viewport">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now :) But, could you please what it is doing and how you decreased my code so much?

Comment: Sure, I added more explanation here.